# I am having the issue on tomcat server@local host[Stopped,Synchronized]

Tags: tomcat, server

Under any such circumstances, without going for re-installing the server simply we can follow this way to resolve it.

Comment: What's the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to handle such type of exceptions are ---> Under eclipse, go to Window menu then choose Preferences-->Server-->Runtime Environments--->Edit--->Browse the location of your tomcat apache got installed--->finish---->ok.    Now select  Project Explorer  then choose Server--->next--->select tomcat server type--->next-->Add project--->Finish. 
Now go ahead with your work.